# Zend2 Framework Conditional Layout

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

I am not sure how to handle this scenario, but I am sure it is simple.
Pages within my site are handled via a layout, but I have an index that is independent of the rest... how do I present that page without directing it through the layout?

tia

Comment: Like all pages have Layout `foo` but only IndexController::indexAction has layout `bar`?   Inside controller: `$this->layout('bar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a controller action, create a new view model instance and pass the view parameters.

```
$view = new ViewModel($params);
```

Disable the view from rendering the layout.

```
$view->setTerminal(true);
```

Set the view script path to the file you need to render without the layout

```
$view->setTemplate('/module-name/controller-name/view-file-name');
```

Return the view model

```
return $view;
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was going to be something simple.